# Why does the Rails low-cruft concern cause the module to lose its constants?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, separation-of-concerns, activesupport-concern

I have an Orderable concern in Rails 4.2 with a constant "Complete". `app/models/concerns/orderable.rb`:

```
module Orderable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  COMPLETE = "Complete"
end
```

In Rails console I am able to run `Orderable.constants`, which returns `[:COMPLETE]`. However, if I change the Orderable concern to the "low-cruft" style described in the [Rails **concerning** module](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.8/classes/Module/Concerning.html#method-i-concern) like so:

```
concern :Orderable do
  COMPLETE = "Complete"
end
```

then running `Orderable.constants` in Rails console returns `[]`. The Rails documentation says that the "low-cruft short cut to define a concern ... is equivalent." Why does this single change have the affect of losing access to the module's constants? Do I need to redefine them somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to actually be a flaw in how the concern "macro" is implemented:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

class Module
    # A low-cruft shortcut to define a concern.
    #
    #   concern :EventTracking do
    #     ...
    #   end
    #
    # is equivalent to
    #
    #   module EventTracking
    #     extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    #
    #     ...
    #   end
    def concern(topic, &module_definition)
      const_set topic, Module.new {
        extend ::ActiveSupport::Concern
        module_eval(&module_definition)
      }
    end
  end
  include Concerning
end
```

This code monkeypatches the ruby Module object to provide a `concern` method.

The key here is `module_eval(&module_definition)` which does not properly evaluate the block in the context of the new module being defined.

What actually happens when you run:

```
concern :Orderable do
  COMPLETE = "Complete"
end

::COMPLETE
# => "Complete"
```

Is that you´re declaring the constant `COMPLETE` in the main object. Ooops!

To work properly it should look like this:

```
def concern(topic, &module_definition)
  const_set topic, Module.new do |m|
    extend ::ActiveSupport::Concern
    m.module_eval(&module_definition)
  end
end
```

I would avoid using the "low-cruft" syntax until this is fixed.